# Rings Trapped Between Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

***Some Background and Motivation:*** In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161381/why-does-the-integral-domain-being-trapped-between-a-finite-field-extension-im), it is shown that an integral domain $D$ such that $F \subset D \subset E$, $E$ and $F$ fields with $[E:F]$ finite, is itself a field.  However, a significantly more general result holds and seems worthy, of independent address; hence,

Let

$F \subset E \tag 1$

be fields with

$[E:F] < \infty; \tag 2$

if $R$ is a ring such that

$F \subset R \subset E, \tag 3$

show that $R$ is in fact a field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intermediate ring between a field and an algebraic extension.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44374/intermediate-ring-between-a-field-and-an-algebraic-extension) Note that finite implies algebraic.

Comment: It also seems your question is a duplicate of the other reference you just edited in.

Comment: Isn't the second theorem exactly the same as the first one, except for the additional observation that subrings of integral domains are integral domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in R\setminus F$, then for some minimal $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x$ is a root of a polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^nc_ix^i$ over $F$ of degree $n$. Otherwise, $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$ is a basis of an infinite dimensional vector space over $F$, but $[E:F]$ is finite. And note that $c_0\neq0$. Otherwise $x$ would be a zero-divisor, and this all happens within field $E$.

So for any $x\in R\setminus F$, you have $x\cdot\overbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{c_0}\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_ix^{n-1}\right)}^{\in R}=1$. So $R$ contains the inverse of $x$.

Comment: It is not the case that eventually $x^n \in F$, rather that $x^n$ is eventually a linear combination of smaller powers. Your reasoning would imply, for instance, that all finite extensions are given by radicals which is not true.

Comment: @TokenToucan Thanks. Rattling things off too quickly.

Comment: Also it isn't necessarily the case that $c_0 \neq 0$ but if it does you can always factor out $x$'s and cancel them (since one is in a domain) to get a linear combination which has a nonzero constant term.

Comment: @TokenToucan I think it is necessarily the case that $c_0\neq0$ if $n$ is minimal, which was my intent.